# Modify Woocommerce Shortcode [product id=""]

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to modify the existing wordpress woocommerce single product shortcode, (ie: [product id="2020"]

This shortcode will display the product by id and description.

My goal is to use a modified shortcode on a normal "page" & display the product with gallery (and it's thumbnails) as it would display per single product page.

[image]

Comment: You could create your own shortcode man, You shouldn't modify a plugin directly because if it updates your codes will be lost. If you know the basic construct of a shortcode you could just use this [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) and [get_the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/). That way you will get the title and description of the product.

Comment: Thank you rai, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I have much to learn, MUCH to learn.  I am a novice but I will try.

Comment: gave an answer on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function show_my_product_callback($atts)
{
    $a = shortcode_atts(array( 
        'product_id' => ''),$atts );

    echo get_the_title($a['product_id']);
    echo get_the_content($a['product_id']);
}

add_shortcode( 'show_my_product', 'show_my_product_callback' );
```

on using it: [show_my_product product_id='3']

more reading resources.

[get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) - for the custom fields.

[get_post_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) - for the product description.

[get_the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) - for the name of the product.

Comment: Hi Rai, thank you kindly for taking the time to provide me with the code.  I have tried it technically works, but it only displays the short description information, nothing else like any gallery media.  Is that because I need to figure it out myself?  Thanks again, I hope I can return the favor..